# unable to install java gem for jruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jruby

I need to install java gem for my jruby package.
The below is the error it gives me.

C:\Users\abcd>jruby -v

jruby 1.7.19 (1.9.3p551) 2015-01-29 20786bd on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_31-b13 +jit [Windows 7-amd64]

C:\Users\abcd>jgem install java

io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
ERROR:  Error installing java:
        java requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.

From irb console when I say 
require 'java'
this gives me 'false' always

Answer (score 0):

If you look at https://github.com/vanruby/java/blob/master/java.gemspec you'll see ruby version must be **>= 2.1.0**

This is the same as the error you got.

**jruby 1.7.19** has only 2 modes: **1.8** and **1.9** modes.

If you want ruby modes >= 2.x, you need to move to jruby-9k, not yet released but a pre-2 version is available for tests:

http://jruby.org/2015/04/28/jruby-9-0-0-0-pre2.html

jruby 9k pre2 has ruby mode **2.2.2** and the installation will work nicely:

> jruby -v

`jruby 9.0.0.0.pre2 (2.2.2) 2015-04-28 2755ae0 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.45-b02 on 1.8.0_45-b14 +jit [Windows 7-amd64]`

> jgem ins -l java-0.0.2.gem

`Successfully installed java-0.0.2
1 gem installed`

Please note in my case I downloaded the gem locally, as I've some internal network restrictions.

Comment: I have tried out downloading the below 2 versions
JRuby 9.0.0.0.pre2 Windows Executable (x64) (md5, sha1)
JRuby 9.0.0.0.pre2 Binary .zip (md5, sha1)
the problem is they don't have all the files & folders required, they don't have the gem or jgem.bat files to update gems.

Comment: Moreover, it always says

C:\jruby-9.0.0.0.pre2\bin>jruby -v
Error: Could not find or load main class org.jruby.Main

I have also tried out  the below
C:\jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1\bin>jruby -v
Error: Could not find or load main class org.jruby.Main
Any help ?

Comment: Sure I can help. If you have java8, ant and ivy installed on your Windows server, have a look at this small jruby distribution I made. https://github.com/cmichon/jruby-ant . To install it in 9k-pre2 mode, just type ant, then '9' at the prompt. I've jgem inside it.

Comment: hey... I'm not into those ant and ivy, can you just zip the code, upload and provide me a link over here ?

Comment: @SrichandarKarpuram maybe you could try https://s3.amazonaws.com/jruby.org/downloads/9.0.0.0.pre2/jruby-complete-9.0.0.0.pre2.jar instead of my own distribution ? Execute jgem like this: ```java -jar jruby-complete-9.0.0.0.pre2.jar -S jgem```. Same goes for jirb: ```java -jar jruby-complete-9.0.0.0.pre2.jar -S jirb```

Answer (score 0):

the **java** gem is a "joke" around Java ... JRuby on the other hand provides you "serious" access to the full underlying Java APIs and actually internally already has a `require 'java'` (it's always loaded by default since JRuby 1.7.x thus `$LOADED_FEATURES` will always have *java* loaded).

although this might sound like not an answer - do not use `gem 'java'` under JRuby it's author probably never tried JRuby and did not realize it will collide and give users a hard time (in general it's best to avoid Ruby-ists joking around Java since they occasionally produce non thread-safe code).

Answer (score -1):

To get JRuby on your system, install the most recent JRuby binary file for your system, extract it, and then work with it from the command line in a terminal window or command window

Comment: I have already installed the latest JRuby binary file on my system.
So, now tell me if there's any alternative

Comment: Once you've downloaded JRuby installation and it is located in the directory /opt/jruby, you'll need to add /opt/jruby/bin to the end of your $PATH environment variable. if you've done this comment again if not try this and if it dosen't work comment again and i will try to get back to you

Comment: @SrichandarKarpuram this is not the most recent jruby binary version. you need to upgrade to jruby-9k-pre2. Please see my answer.

Comment: I have also added them to the system path variables, still I have been facing problem